# Passing arguments to functions without copying them in JULIA-LANG

Tags: parameter-passing, julia

let's say I need to create one huge array and use it during my program inside another function. I want to do this without copying this array every time I use it. I know that if I simply give them as argument Julia has a call-by-sharing mechanism and it won't copy the arguments. But if I do something as following, will it still be able to operate without creating copies every time in the loop ?:

```
function main()
    huge_arr = ones(Float32,20000,30000)
    another_arr = rand(4,5)
    coupled_var = (huge_arr,another_arr)
    for i=1:100  
        target_function(coupled_var)
    end
end

function target_function(x)
   my_first_var = x[1]
   my_second_var = x[2] 
   # some operations here 
end
```

Comment: The quick answer is yes. The value of an array is its pointer, so what will be passed is essentially just the pointer to the same slab of memory. There's no copying when passing in Julia (unless you do it manually of course). This is why mutating functions (like `A_mul_B!`) work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are manipulating Arrays that are **mutable** objects (declared as `mutable struct Array{...} ...`), hence there are passed by reference semantics.

```
function target_function(x)
   my_first_var = x[1]        # x[1],x[2] are _mutable_ objects 
   my_second_var = x[2]       # -> this only create a new binding (no copy)
   # some operations here 
end
```

You can check that `my_first_var` and `x[1]` are pointing on the same object using [pointer_from_objref](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/c/#Base.pointer_from_objref).

Examples:

```
function foo(x) 
   y = x
   println("Check ptr $(pointer_from_objref(x) == pointer_from_objref(y)) x:$(pointer_from_objref(x)) y:$(pointer_from_objref(y))")
end
```

then try:

```
x=4.5
foo(x)
Check ptr false x:Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a28a2850 y:Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a28a2860
```

-> for a `Float64`, y=x performs a **deep** copy

```
x=rand(5)
foo(x)
Check ptr true x:Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a284a410 y:Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a284a410
```

-> for an array, y=x performs a **shallow** copy (share same memory address)

Note: in your `target_function` take care of using component level operations, like `my_first_var .*= 2` because something like  `my_first_var *= 2` **creates a new variable**.

For instance:

```
julia> pointer_from_objref(x)
Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a043f890   <-
                                  |
julia> x *= 2                     |
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 3.81254
 3.60607
 2.86026
 1.94396
 2.91994                        different memory
                                  |
julia> pointer_from_objref(x)     |
Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a0afa210  <--|
                                  |
julia> x .*= 2
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 7.62507
 7.21214
 5.72052
 3.88793
 5.83987                     same memory
                                 |
julia> pointer_from_objref(x)    |
Ptr{Void} @0x00007f25a0afa210 <--|
```

Comment: That is a great answer! Thanks for sharing the `pointer_from_objref` function, very useful for debugging.

Comment: @PicaudVincent sorry I was late to accept the answer. I would thank you for both detailed answer and reference for the `pointer_from_objref` function