# Modifying values in a function with an internal function! call

Tags: function, julia

Say I want to write a function that makes all bools false:

```
function true_to_false!(boolean::Bool)
    boolean = false
end
```

Why can I then not use this to change the values of another function? e.g.:

```
function make_x_false()
    x = true
    true_to_false!(x)
    return x
end
```

Returns `true`.

Of course there are workarounds such as

```
function make_x_false()
    x = true
    x = true_to_false!(x) 
end
```

and

```
function make_x_false!(x)
    x = true_to_false!(x) 
end
```

But I have a case where these would make for some very messy code!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia is using pass-by-sharing mechanism see also [How to pass an object by reference and value in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150295/how-to-pass-an-object-by-reference-and-value-in-julia)

In practice this means that a function can mutate its argument when it is a `mutable struct`, `Dict` or an `Array` but primitive types cannot be mutated - they are just recreated inside the function.

Hence you can use for an example `Ref` do achieve the desired effect:

```
julia> function  make_x_false!(x::Ref{Bool})
           x[] = false
       end;


julia> u = Ref{Bool}(true)
Base.RefValue{Bool}(true)


julia> u[]
true

julia> make_x_false!(u);

julia> u[]
false
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @przemyslaw-szufel