# How Can i create function like append!() in julia?

Tags: julia

I need to create a function like append!
I think ! Like a pointer and can change the function of the argument an and make changes to the main variable without return argument

Comment: This is where you need to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150295/how-to-pass-an-object-by-reference-and-value-in-julia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about `!` at the language level - it's just a convention that the Julia community decided upon to mark functions that mutate their argument.

> I think ! Like a pointer and can change the function of the argument

Functions with `!` at the end get the same argument as any other function, no pointers or any other special changes involved.

```
julia> set2to2!(a::Array) = a[2] = 2
set2to2! (generic function with 1 method)
```

This is a mutating function that sets the second index of its argument to 2.

```
julia> set2to2(a::Array) = a[2] = 2
set2to2 (generic function with 1 method)
```

This is also a mutating function, that does the same thing, even though it doesn't end in a `!`. There's no difference in what it has access to, and how it works.

The `!` just lets the caller know that your function is going to be changing the value of the argument they pass in, and so is considered good practice for program design.