# Problem with interlinked dictionaries in Julia

Tags: loops, dictionary, julia, interaction, dictionary-comprehension

I have a problem regarding values set in a dictionary. I don't understand why they are changed unintentionally within a loop.
Here, x_exog["B_l_pre"][2] changed from 0.5 to 0.525, but I only specified x_exog["B_l_post"][2] to change. Why ?

```
## Parameters and set up the environment
# Set exogenous parameters
x_exog = Dict{String, Any}()

# set amenity
x_exog["B_l_pre"] = [1;0.5;2]
x_exog["B_h_pre"] = [1;0.5;2]
x_exog["B_l_post"] = x_exog["B_l_pre"]
x_exog["B_h_post"] = x_exog["B_h_pre"]


x_exog_baseline = x_exog
# define the parameters
shock = "amenity"

for run in ["baseline","pro_poor_program", "pro_rich_program" ]
    
    # set the initial values for exogenous variables
    local x_exog = x_exog_baseline
    x_exog["run"] = run
    x_exog["shock"] = shock

    # define the policy shock
    if shock == "amenity"
        # improve amenity slum
        
        if run == "pro_poor_program"
            x_exog["B_l_post"][2] = x_exog["B_l_post"][2] * 1.05

        elseif run == "pro_rich_program"
            x_exog["B_h_post"][2] = x_exog["B_h_post"][2] * 1.05

        else            
            x_exog["B_l_post"][2] = x_exog["B_l_post"][2] * 1.05
            x_exog["B_h_post"][2] = x_exog["B_h_post"][2] * 1.05
        end
        
    end
    print(x_exog["B_l_pre"][2], x_exog["B_h_pre"][2]) ###Why the loop has changed x_exog["B_l_pre"] and x_exog["B_h_pre"] ?????
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia uses pass-by-sharing (see this SO question [How to pass an object by reference and value in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150295/how-to-pass-an-object-by-reference-and-value-in-julia)).

Basically, for primitive types the assignment operator assigns a value while for complex types a reference is assigned. In result both `x_exog["B_l_post"]` and  `x_exog["B_l_pre"]` point to the same memory location (`===` compares mutable objects by address in memory):

```
julia> x_exog["B_l_post"] === x_exog["B_l_pre"]
true
```

what you need to do is to create a copy of the object:

```
x_exog["B_l_post"] = deepcopy(x_exog["B_l_pre"])
```

Now they are two separate objects just having the same value:

```
julia> x_exog["B_l_post"] === x_exog["B_l_pre"]
false

julia> x_exog["B_l_post"] == x_exog["B_l_pre"]
true
```

Hence in your case

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple. Because you said:

```
x_exog["B_l_post"] = x_exog["B_l_pre"]
```

And remeber that you specified the `x_exog["B_l_pre"]` as:

```
x_exog["B_l_pre"] = [1;0.5;2]
```

So the `x_exog["B_l_post"]` refers to the same object in the memory as the `x_exog["B_l_pre"]` refers to. To avoid this, you can pass a copy of `x_exog["B_l_pre"]` to the `x_exog["B_l_post"]`:

```
julia> x_exog["B_l_post"] = copy(x_exog["B_l_pre"])
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.5
 2.0

julia> x_exog["B_l_post"][2] = 2
2

julia> x_exog["B_l_post"]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 2.0

julia> x_exog["B_l_pre"]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.5
 2.0
```

As you can see, I changed the second element of the `x_exog["B_l_post"]` into 2, but this change doesn't happen in the `x_exog["B_l_pre"]` because these are two separated objects now.

Comment: Ok I see, but I was expecting that x_exog["B_l_post"] = x_exog["B_l_pre"] would just copy and not refers to a similar object. Thanks!