# Replacing Variable Name with a String in a Julia Macro

Tags: macros, julia, expression

I’m working on a project where I need to create a macro in Julia that takes a Julia code expression, a variable name, and a string as input and returns the same expression with the specified variable name replaced by the given string. It’s important that the macro respects variable scoping in Julia.

For example, if I have the following expression:

```
x = 42
expr = :(2 * x + 3)
```

And I call the macro with the variable name x and the replacement string “y”, like this:

```
@my_macro expr x "y"
```

I want to get the modified expression:

```
:(2 * y + 3)
```

I’ve been trying to implement this macro, but I’m having trouble dealing with variable scoping and ensuring that the replacement only occurs for the specified variable.

I’d appreciate any guidance or assistance in implementing this macro correctly. If anyone has any insights, code snippets, or advice on how to achieve this in Julia, please share them with me.

Comment: This isn't possible with a macro — macros only see the expressions passed to them, but not their values (because macros run at compile time but the values only exist at runtime). If you were ok passing the expression literally to the macro, then it would work, but you can't assign to a variable `expr` and then pass `express` to `@my_macro`

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the expression as argument to macro

Answer (score 3):

You could define the following function:

```
using AbstractTrees
function replace!(expr::Expr, old_val::Symbol, new_val::Symbol) 
    for e in collect(PreOrderDFS(expr))
        if typeof(e) <: Expr
            ix = findfirst(==(old_val), e.args)
            if !isnothing(ix) 
                e.args[ix] = new_val
            end
        end
    end
    expr
end
```

Now this function can be used such as:

```
julia> replace!(quote; f(x,z) = 2x+4z; end, :x, :y)
quote
    #= REPL[61]:1 =#
    f(y, z) = begin
            #= REPL[61]:1 =#
            2y + 4z
        end
end
```

This can be used inside a macro such as:

```
macro replace(mycode, oldval, newval)
    replace!(mycode, oldval.value, newval.value)
end
```

Which can be used as:

```
julia> x=1; y=100;

julia> @replace(3x+y, :x, :y)
400
```

Comment: Here, in loop:  for e in collect(PreOrderDFS(expr)), why modifying e.args is reflected in expr but modifying e doesn't.

Comment: what do you mean by "modifying `e`" ? `e` is a local variable this loop that holds a reference. So we are getting a set of references as local variables and then we modify their fields. Perhaps this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150295/how-to-pass-an-object-by-reference-and-value-in-julia

Comment: I want to modify the node of expr tree directly. not any arg of expr.